# Virtual Device Manager Disabled in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, sdk, android-virtual-device, android-studio

I have installed Android Studio on my Windows 7 PC. But I cannot create the virtual devices on the studio as the button for AVD and SDK is disabled by default. How ca I enable them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well I found the problem. The `gradle` was not installed as my internet connection was not active. Make sure the Android Studio installs the `gradle` when you first start and create a project.

Answer (score 5):

I haven't seen this error myself, but try going to
`File -> Project Structure -> SDKs` and make sure you have a listing for the Android SDK and that the home path is pointing to the correct location.

[image: example]

Comment: Thanks for help. But I found the solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Go to the android-studio\sdk\tools\lib and search for AVD Manager and SDK Manager. If they are present, try running them.

While I do not know the actual reason for the disabled buttons, but this might just help in troubleshooting the problem.

Comment: These are not present in the "android-studio\sdk\tools\lib" but at "Android\android-sdk-windows". Does it make any difference?